# Create multi dimensional array in cakephp

Tags: html, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array

Now I have 3 row of data.

```
id  name    date
1   data1   12-06-2013
2   data2   12-06-2013
3   data3   16-06-2013
```

now I want to group the 3 rows of data into a new array, something like:

```
Array
(
   [2013-06-12] => Array
   (
     [0] => data1
     [1] => data2
   )
   [2013-06-16] => Array
   (
    [0] => data3
   )
)
```

the question is 1st i using foreach to show all date out.
`<?php foreach($datax as $data):`
`echo $data['Model_Name']['id'];`
`endforeach;?>`

then, while i looping i want to group up the `$data` sort to date as the multidimensional array as above.

Comment: then what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try below method,. you can add an additional column for date

```
$a = array(
array('datax' => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'data1')),
array('datax' => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'data2')),
array('datax' => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'data3'))
);
    $result = Set::classicExtract($a, '{n}.datax.id');
     /* $result now looks like:
            Array
            (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            )
    */


    $result = Set::classicExtract($a, '{n}.datax.name');
    /* $result now looks like:
        Array
        (
            [0] => data1
            [1] => data2
            [2] => data3
        )
    */
```

Comment: now the problem is i am not intended to group all the data to separately. i just want group up the data as a date array() if the date of each data is same.